# How to get even the distance when querying from MongoDB (geospatial concept)

Tags: mongodb

I am using this query in Robomongo/cli to get the records which are nearest to the given co-ordinate which is working correctly.

Now how do I get the even the distance from same query?

Below is my query

```
db.places.find(
{
    loc : 
    { 
        $near : 
        { 
            $geometry : 
            {
                type : "Point",
                coordinates : [12.974729, 77.609375],
                $maxDistance : 2000
            }
        }
    }
)
```

JSON Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c6becd8586e7a757260d62"),
    "name" : "address here",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            12.9802900000000001, 
            77.5857400000000013
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GeoNear](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) command which returns stats, including [average distance](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#geoNear.stats.avgDistance):

```
db.runCommand( {
    geoNear: "places" ,
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [12.974729, 77.609375] },
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: 2000
}).stats.avgDistance
```

Comment: I am not able run it gives "no geo index :(" error.   I am using mongo 2.2.0 version number

Comment: You need a geo index to use geospatial queries.

Comment: Is this the command db.places.ensureIndex( { 'loc' : "2dsphere" } ); should be used to create geo index.  My json document is updated in the post

Comment: Are you asking how to use geospat queries in general, or how to get average distance?

Comment: when I run your query its giving the error has "exception: geo values have to be numbers: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 12.974729, 77.609375 ] }"

Comment: the query which you gave works fine in local system which is 2.6.10.  Same query when i run on server which is 2.2.0 i get  "exception: geo values have to be numbers: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 12.974729, 77.609375 ] }"

Comment: Geoindexes changed several times since v2.2, including `$near` command, which did not support geoJson you posted in the query, but it is completely separate story. As a side note, I would strongly suggest use the same version of the db in dev and prod to avoid frustration.